# Error: Intentando Obtener propiedad de un no-objeto

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

estoy teniendo el siguente error al tratar de obtener el valor idEtapa de esta forma $actividad->etapa->idEtapa.

[image: Error en el Log]

tengo el mismo error accediendo de esta forma: $actividad->etapa['idEtapa'].

mi Codigo es este:

```
public function GuardarCronograma($actividades, $idConvocatoria)
{
    Log::debug('-------------------  Cronograma de Actividades  ------------------------');
    Log::debug($actividades);
    foreach ($actividades as $actividad) {
        $cronograma = new ConvocatoriaCronograma;
        $cronograma->idEtapa = $actividad->etapa->idEtapa;
        $cronograma->idConvocatoria = $idConvocatoria;
        $cronograma->idAreaResponsable = $actividad->arearesponsable->idAreaResponsable;
        $cronograma->fechai = $actividad->fechai;
        $cronograma->fechaf = $actividad->fechaf;
        $cronograma->descripcion = $actividad->textactividades;
        $cronograma->save();
        Log::debug('- '.$actividad->etapa->nombre.' fi:'.$actividad->fechai.' ff:'.$actividad->fechaf);
    }
}
```

cada $actividad se ve de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradezco de antemano :)

Comment: Intentalo asi: `$actividad["etapa"]["idEtapa"]`

Comment: @alanfcm si me dio como me dices, gracias bro :)

Comment: Si en alguna parte creaste un array `$actividades` desde un JSON usando `json_encode`, puedes quitar el parámetro `TRUE` de esa función y entonces podrás tratar el objeto como lo estás haciendo, con la notación `objeto->propiedad`, en vez de `objeto["propiedad"]`. Es mucho más elegante y si el objeto es un JSON lo mantienes como lo que es, sin necesidad de convertirlo a array.

Comment: @A.Cedano el array $actividades lo creo en la vista(blade) y lo mando usando vue-axios y llega de esa forma al metodo. Como podria hacer para que al llegar al metodo lo convierta y pueda usarlo como objeto->propiedad, nota: puedo usar normalmente objeto->propiedad pero cuando tiene mas niveles ya no ($objeto->propiedad->propiedad).

Comment: El problema es que no sé usar ni `blade` ni `vue-axios`. Pero supongo que deben tener alguna forma de respetar el objeto sin convertirlo, de forma que si es un JSON lo dejen como tal. Eso puedes investigarlo en la documentación de esos frameworks o alguien que tenga experiencia con ellos podrá decírtelo. Yo sé que en PHP, para evitar que un JSON se convertido a array, sólo hay que ejecutar `json_encode` sin el parámetro `TRUE` al final.